# GCP & Tensorflow - Runtime Error Prediction Failed

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, tensorflow-serving

I have trained a model using GCP Datalab, hosted it on Cloud ML Engine and am now trying to request predictions from the model.  For some reason, I am receiving the error below.

```
RuntimeError: Prediction failed: Error during model execution: AbortionError(code=StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT, details="NodeDef mentions attr 'dilations' not in Op<name=Conv2D; signature=input:T, filter:T -> output:T; attr=T:type,allowed=[DT_HALF, DT_FLOAT, DT_DOUBLE]; attr=strides:list(int); attr=use_cudnn_on_gpu:bool,default=true; attr=padding:string,allowed=["SAME", "VALID"]; attr=data_format:string,default="NHWC",allowed=["NHWC", "NCHW"]>; NodeDef: cl-words-3/conv = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, _output_shapes=[[-1,757,1,128]], data_format="NHWC", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="VALID", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](embedding/ExpandDims, cl-words-3/W/read)
     [[Node: cl-words-3/conv = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, _output_shapes=[[-1,757,1,128]], data_format="NHWC", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="VALID", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](embedding/ExpandDims, cl-words-3/W/read)]]")
```

I suspect that I am receiving this error because the version of TensorFlow is mismatched between Cloud ML Engine ([v1.4](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/runtime-version-list)) and Datalab (v1.5). The main reason I suspect this is that I have trained a model on AWS SageMaker using TensorFlow v1.4 and I am able to upload the model to Cloud ML and request predictions with no issue.

How do I downgrade the version of TensorFlow in Datalab? Could this be caused by any other reason than version mismatch?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this problem was due to the mismatch referenced in my question.  I added the following line of code to the start of my script in Datalab and now it works.

```
!pip install tensorflow==1.4
```

I am not knowledgeable enough in this area to verify whether this is the recommended way to install tensorflow 1.4 for datalab or whether environment conflicts can arise, but can state that it worked to fix the problem.

This appears to be quite a big incompatibility between GCP's own suite of products, which I think they need to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Support here!

Our backline team is working on releasing TFv1.5.

I've opened a feature request on your behalf, you can keep track of it on the Google Issue Tracker by following this link [1]

You can use the "star" on  the top left corner of the Public Issue Tracker entry [1] to get updates on the state of the request.

[1] https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/74319349

Comment: Thanks for the reply Paula.  Do you know if they have already changed the version? I am once again getting a similar issue after training on datalab in v1.4 and using Cloud ML engine: RuntimeError: Prediction failed: Error during model execution: AbortionError(code=StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT, 
details="NodeDef mentions attr 'output_type' not in Op<name=ArgMax; signature=input:T, dimension:Tidx -> 
output:int64.

Comment: The current Cloud ML Runtime Version includes: 

Runtime Version 1.4 uses TensorFlow 1.4.0 for online prediction, and 1.4.1 for batch prediction and training.

Python 3.5 is available for training with Runtime Version 1.4. The Ubuntu packages for Python 3 (installed when running in Python 3 training).

https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/runtime-version-list